# z.test or t.test when n is large, but variance unknown?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to decide whether to do a `t.test` or a `z.test` in **R** to check the hypothesis if two samples have the same mean, $\mu_1 = \mu_2$ with a 95% certainty.

What I know is that we use `t.test` if $\sigma^2$ is unknown and should be approximated. In my case the samples sizes are $S_1 = 1000$ and $S_2 = 1000$. So, I have quite a big sample, and if I check the t-values when $df = 999$ and $\alpha = 0.025$ they have approximately the same values as the z-values, from a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

So according to the central limit theorm, can I do a `z.test` and assume $\sigma^2 = 1$, or should I stick to the `t.test` with the ridiculously degree of freedom size?

Since $t \sim(\infty) = \mathcal{N}(0,1) $

Can I assume $\sigma^2 = 1$ ?

Comment: What you can do is estimate the variances from the samples and use the asymptotic normal distribution, instead of the t-distribution, for large sample sizes. But I do not get why you would assume that $\sigma^2=1$.

Comment: Oh, so it is invalid to assume that since the t distribution converges to a normal(0,1) ?

Comment: The $t$ score is calculated the same as the $z$ score, its just its interpretation that changes. If your sample is from a gaussian population, then there really will be very little difference. If your population is not normal, then either test may not be appropriate.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you mean. You are refering to the t-ratio, not the actual random variables. Yes in that case the limiting distribution is standard normal and you may use the standard normal distribution for inference. Yet, be careful. It is the standardized difference of the variables that has the standard normal distribution.

Comment: It really depends on how fast your sample means converge towards normality. If your sample skew coefficient is relatively low and there is a low excess kurtosis, then I'd be more confident in using the asymptotic results.

Comment: The mean of $S_1$ is 0.01617238, and of $S_2$ 0.0162655, if that helps?

Comment: What are your sample skews and kurtosis'?

Comment: with $n = 1000$, it is very unlikely that there would be enough skew or kurtosis to matter. Unless we're talking about return on lottery tickets or something...

Comment: $S_1$ skew = 7.188721, kurtosis = 108.4216. $S_2$ skew = 2.061314, kurtosis = 6.982496.

Comment: @CliffAB totally agree...and the sample values confirm this. The normal approximation should be quite accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer: you should do a t-test, rather than a z-test (although you are correct in that the results will be nearly identical).

The long answer: yes, it is true that as $df \rightarrow \infty$, $t_{df} \rightarrow_D N(0,1)$, i.e. that as the degrees of freedom approach infinity, a t distribution approaches a normal distribution. *Historically*, this was very useful, as most statisticians did not have access to the table of quantiles for, say, a $t_{5023}$ distribution. But with modern computers, this is not a problem at all. You are correct in that there would be very little inaccuracy in using a z-test instead of a t-test with $df = 999$. But given that nowadays, it is just as easy to use a t-test as a z-test, there is no reason not to.

Also, I may be misinterpreting what you said, but I wanted to clear up some confusion just in case. In the z-test, we have

$\frac{\bar x_1 - \bar x_2}{ \sqrt{ \sigma_1^2/n_1 + \sigma_2^2/n_2 } } \sim N(0,1)$ under the null hypothesis.

So if you wanted to approximate a t-test with a z-test, you would use $s_1$ and $s_2$ for $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, not $\sigma = 1$. But perhaps I'm a little confused on what you meant when you said "use $\sigma = 1$", i.e. this would be the standard deviation of the reference distribution.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Dont you need to subtract the means aswell in the numerator, $\bar{x_1} - \bar{x_2} - (\mu_1 - \mu_2)$ ?

Comment: @Isbister yes, but (typically), under the null hypothesis, $\mu_1 = \mu_2$, so that part vanishes. The way you wrote it is a little more general.

Comment: Oh, true...A bit off-topic, but when are the means considered to be equal? in reality they are almost never equal. But how much can they differ? 0.001, 0.01? :)

Comment: Speaking as a statistician, I would say they are *never* considered (exactly) equal. What makes better sense is to ask something like "are we certain that $|\mu_1-\mu_2|<\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is some value small enough that this difference is ignorable in the real world". This question is bested answered with a confidence interval. For example, if my 95% CI for the difference is (-0.1, 0.2), and I only consider differences of 1.0 or more to have a practical difference, then I can conclude there's no practical difference between the two groups.

Comment: what you consider $\epsilon$ (i.e. the maximum ignorable difference) entirely depends on the nature of your data.